# I need help identifying this womens bike frame, please

Tags: frames, identify-this-bike, vintage

[image]

[image]

It's nearly 70 years old. I've narrowed the potentials down to Sears, Schwinn or possibly J.C. Higgins. I did just order the wheels for this and it takes 26" schwinn apparently as opposed to standard 26". I'm restoring it from the rusted hunk that it was. :-)

Comment: Welcome to Bicycles StackExchange.  Sounds like you have made some good initial research attempts so far. Please attach a few pictures as it will help a lot. Any emblems, unique items are helpful.

Comment: I thought I did attach a picture. It looked like it took. I'll try again.

Comment: Yeah, Schwinn, Sears, or J C Higgins.  I wouldn't guess 70 years old, but maybe 50.

Comment: Well, my wife was riding it when she was a kid 50 years ago and she got it as a hand me down from her sister who is 10 years older than her so it has to be older than that.

Comment: I would think that Schwinn might be a little easier to track down and check via an internet search, just from it's history.  There were notable Schwinn models that have some collector interest, which may yield some motivation for someone to have collected that type of information.  I found one at https://bikehistory.org/ but that was just a 30-second search.  There probably are more.

Comment: I've looked through thousands of images, searching on twin top tube bicycles (the seat this one had on it leads me to believe it is early 60's so about 60 years old, not 70. But I have not had any luck finding this specific frame so far. A few that are similar but nothing quite like this one.

Comment: So I was able to find the serial number on the bottom bracket shell but it's difficult to make out but appears to be R68 473S9 or possibly R68147359. The R68 is very clear. The next space could have been a character or perhaps it was just scratched. Looks like possibly a 1 but really impossible to say. The 3 after the 7 could also be an 8 and it's not clear if it is a 5 or an S. Again, really can't tell. The final number does appear to be a 9. looking it up, "R" denotes nothing as far as the month as far as I can tell but the 68 could denote the year I believe